How to output multiple lines using asio::stream_file::async_write_some?
There is overload of asio::stream_file::async_write_some function that accepts sequence of buffers. But in my case (see the code below) it outputs only the content of the first buffer, and right now I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Of course it is possible to write code that outputs the first buffer and register callback that outputs the second buffer (and register callback that outputs the third buffer and so on). But I hope there is simpler solution?
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/stream_file.hpp>

namespace asio = boost::asio;

...

    const std::vector<std::string> lines{
        "first line\n", 
        "second line\n", 
        "third line\n"
    };
    std::vector<asio::const_buffer> buffers;
    buffers.reserve(lines.size());
    for (const auto& line : lines) {
        buffers.push_back(asio::buffer(line.data(), line.size()));
    }

    asio::io_context ctx;
    const char* output_path = R"(C:\Users\MyUsername\workspace\temp\lines.txt)";
    asio::stream_file stream(ctx);
    stream.open(
        output_path,
        asio::stream_file::write_only|asio::stream_file::create
    );
    stream.async_write_some(
        buffers, 
        [](boost::system::error_code e, size_t n) {
            if (e != boost::system::errc::success) {
                std::cerr << "error, ec=" << e << " size=" << n << std::endl;
            }
        }
    );
    ctx.run();

And after the program is finished, the content of lines.txt is first line\n.
Operating system: Windows 10, Boost.ASIO version: 103002, Visual Studio Community version: 17.11.4

you can write or single block to file, or multiple blocks (every page_size) with WriteFileGather. in your case you can simply use WriteFile (or NtWriteFile) and all

@RbMm Thank you for telling about WriteFileGather, I didn't know that such function exists. Although in this question I'm more interested in asio-based solution, but still nice thing to know

You simply can do several asynchronous (Zw)WriteFile call, if you have several, buffers. No other way. Asio lib can only do this too. In case socket you can send sevaral buffers in single call due WSABUF in WSASend(To) but this supported only on sockets. If file is local filesystem file in most case write will be synchronous by fact ( especially if you write to the end of file and extend it size)

If you read the docs, you will find that [async_]write_some isn't what you are looking for.
Instead use one of the composed write operations like [async_]write: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_87_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write.html

Note that as the docs state, the composed write operations still call [async_]write_some on the [Async]WriteStream, however many times is necessary on the platform/transport/driver configuration.

Like:
template <typename Range = std::vector<std::string>> void foo(Range const& lines) {
    static constexpr auto to_buffer = [](auto const& s) { return asio::buffer(s); };

    asio::io_context ctx;
    const char* output_path = R"(C:\Users\MyUsername\workspace\temp\lines.txt)";
    asio::stream_file s(ctx, output_path, asio::stream_file::write_only | asio::stream_file::create);

    async_write(s, lines | transform(to_buffer), [](auto ec, size_t n) {
        std::cerr << "completed: " << ec.message() << " n=" << n << std::endl;
    });

    ctx.run();
}

Seeing how the use of blocking ctx.run() merely makes this synchronous, I'd simplify all the way:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/stream_file.hpp>
#include <filesystem>
#include <ranges>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using std::filesystem::path;
using std::ranges::views::transform;

static constexpr auto to_buffer = [](auto const& s) constexpr { return asio::buffer(s); };

size_t foo(path const& p, std::vector<std::string> const& lines) {
    asio::stream_file s(asio::system_executor{}, p,
                        asio::stream_file::write_only | asio::stream_file::create);

    return write(s, lines | transform(to_buffer));
}

#include <format>
int main() {
    foo("three.txt", {"first line\n", "second line\n", "third line\n"});

    auto lines = std::views::iota(1, 10'001) | //
        transform([](int i) { return std::format("line {}\n", i); });
    foo("1000.txt", std::vector(lines.begin(), lines.end()));
}

Since the kernel on Coliru is too old, a local demo:


Have you found this answer? Did it help? Or did you just lose interest?
